# How to load Native dependencies automatically in Maven?

Tags: maven

I have few 'so' files that I need to load in maven java project without having to use System.loadLibrary() method.

I have copied the so files in src/main/resources/ folder. Do I have to mention about them in pom.xml ?

How do I do it ?

I'm getting this error now.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: tcl.lang.Interp.commandComplete(Ljava/lang/String;)Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by loading? Maven is a build system. It will put the files in `src/main/resources/` in your jar. But it does not affect your code at runtime. So it is up to your code to load the libraries at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like your path in loadLibrary is wrong. You know that those files in src/main/resources will be copied by maven into target/classes folder and are available via getClass().getResourcesAsStream()...This might help in using loadLibrary()...

```
ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
url = cl.getResource(name);
if(url != null) {
  file = new File( url.getFile() );
}
```

Comment: Should I load the native libraries in the code ? Is it not done by JVM ?